# How to deal with consecutive missing values of stock price in a time series using python?

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, data-analysis, missing-data

I have a data frame consisting of two-time series describing two different stock prices, spanning over five years with an interval of approximately 2 minutes. I am struggling to decide how to deal with the missing values to build a meaningful model.

Some info about the data frame:-

Total number rows: 1315440

Number of missing values in Series_1:    1113923

Number of missing values in Series_2:     378952

Often there are missing values in 100+ consecutive rows, which is what makes me confused about how to deal with this dataset.

Below is a portion of the data, plots of Series_1 (column 2) and Series_2 (column_3).

[image]

Visualisation of Series_1:
[image]

Visualisation of Series_2:
[image]

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Facebook prophet doesn't require continuous data.  Without meaningful features to go along w/your data, there's no reason not to start w/that package and see how it performs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on where your data come from, the missing data at a given time may mean that at this particular timestamp, out of the two stocks, an order was executed for one but not for the other. There is no reason in fact that two different stocks trade at exactly the same time. Certain dormant stocks with no liquidity can go for a long time without being traded while others are more active. Moreover, given that the precision of the data is down to the microsecond, no surprise that the  trades on both stocks are not necessarily happening at the exact same microsecond. In this cases, it is safe to assume that the price of the stock was the last recorded transaction and update the missing values accordingly. Assuming you are using pandas, you could harmonize it by applying the pandas [fillna method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html). Just make sure to sort your data frame beforehand:

```
df.sort_values('Time', inplace=True)
df['Series1'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
df['Series2'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

Comment: @Rafiul Nakib did that solve your issue or was my answer at least of any use?

Comment: Hi, yes your answer does make a lot of sense and I have implemented it on the first series. Just to play around a bit more, I am now trying to fill up the missing spots in the second series with that said log return method as the frequency of data collected in series 2 is higher than in series 1. The reason I am thinking of doing this is because I am considering the series 2 is of a stock that pays dividends or of which the price is changing at all times as opposed to series 1, so a compounding return makes more sense? Any idea how I may implement this in Python? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Typically companies tend to buy back stock rather than pay dividends. If they do, this happens once yearly so the rest of the time the dividend payment would be already discounted in the price. The fact that a price moves a lot does not mean it is increasing all the time. And if it is it will be reflected in the increase rate between the time interval between which you measure their performance. If at t1 you have s1=100 and s2=100 and at t2 s1=110 (one transaction) s2=110 (10 transactions). The stocks growth rate is the same over t2 - t1. But volatility is higher for the second one.